# How to submit an answer in LeetCode

Tags: python

Hi im just starting to practice programming and i did one of the easy problems of leetcode, which is the one called "Average Salary Excluding the Minimum and Maximum Salary", i code it on my local visual studio and the programm works, but when i try to put it in leetcode when i try to submit it, it says

```
"TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
    loop = int(input("How many salaries are you going to input : "))
Line 18 in <module> (Solution.py)"
```

I understand that the program doesnt take user input to try if the program works, but what things do i have to change in my code for it to work?

```
salary = [] 
i = 0
total = 0
average = 0

def max_min_salaries():
    for i in range(loop):
        min_salary = min(salary)
        max_salary = max(salary)
        average = total - min_salary - max_salary
        average = average / ( loop - 2 )    
    return average   

loop = int(input("How many salaries are you going to input : "))

for i in range(loop):
    salary.append(float(input("Input Salary : ")))
    total = total + salary[i]

average = max_min_salaries()

print("The average salary is : " , average)
```

What things i have to change in order to be able to submit my programm

Comment: It looks like leetcode is using a very old version of python which has quite different behavior for the `input()` function.  Does leetcode give you a choice of python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work, it should be like this :

```
class Solution(object):
    def average(self,salary):
        i = 0
        total = 0
        average = 0
        loop = len(salary)
        total = sum(salary)
        for i in range(loop):
            min_salary = min(salary)
            max_salary = max(salary)
            average = total - min_salary - max_salary
            average = average / ( loop - 2 )    
        return average
```